# The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I keep getting a **`max recursion error`** with this query.

At first I thought it was because a null was being returned and then it would try and match the null values causing the error however, I rewrote my query so nulls aren't returned and the error still occurs.

What would be the best way to rewrite this function, so that the error will not occur

```
WITH EmployeeTree AS
(
    SELECT 
        EMP_SRC_ID_NR Id, USR_ACV_DIR_ID_TE Uuid, 
        CASE Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID 
           WHEN Null THEN '0' 
           ELSE Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID 
        END as  ApprovalManagerId 
    FROM 
        dbo.[tEmployees] as Employees WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
        APV_MGR_EMP_ID = @Id 
        and Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID is not null 
        and Employees.EMP_SRC_ID_NR is not null  

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        EMP_SRC_ID_NR Id, USR_ACV_DIR_ID_TE Uuid, 
        CASE Employees.UPS_ACP_EMP_NR 
           WHEN Null THEN '1' 
           ELSE Employees.UPS_ACP_EMP_NR 
        END as ApprovalManagerId 
    FROM 
        dbo.[tEmployees] as Employees WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
        UPS_ACP_EMP_NR = @Id 
        and Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID is not null 
        and Employees.EMP_SRC_ID_NR is not null  

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        Employees.EMP_SRC_ID_NR, Employees.USR_ACV_DIR_ID_TE, 
        CASE Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID 
            WHEN Null THEN '2' 
            ELSE Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID 
        END  
    FROM 
        dbo.[tEmployees] as Employees WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN 
        EmployeeTree ON Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID = EmployeeTree.Id 
    where  
        Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID is not null 
        and Employees.EMP_SRC_ID_NR is not null             
)
SELECT 
    Id AS [EmployeeId], 
    Uuid AS [EmployeeUuid], 
    ApprovalManagerId AS [ManagerId] 
FROM EmployeeTree
```

Comment: This line could be replaced with `COALESCE()`: `CASE Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID 
           WHEN Null THEN '0' 
           ELSE Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID 
        END as  ApprovalManagerId` = `COALESCE(Employees.APV_MGR_EMP_ID, 0) AS ApprovalManagerID`

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Specify the [maxrecursion option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) at the end of the query:

```
...
from EmployeeTree
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

That allows you to specify how often the CTE can recurse before generating an error.  Maxrecursion 0 allows infinite recursion.

Comment: hmm this worked but the query returned a lot more rows then it should have

Comment: @bugz Maxrecursion 0 does now affect your query, do you have to look for the problem elsewhere

Comment: ahh it was a circular refrence in my data, thanks for the help

Comment: +1 I used this option to debug a similar problem. If the query is infinitely recursive, you have to cancel the query in Management Studio after executing it or the server will spool rows until your client runs out of memory.

Comment: While this might fix the problem in situations where you want the query to recurse very deep, it may be just masking a problem in the query.

Answer (score 42):

it is just a sample to avoid max recursion error. we have to use **option (maxrecursion 365); or option (maxrecursion 0);**

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE datetime; 
DECLARE @EntDt datetime; 
set @STARTDATE = '01/01/2009';  
set @EntDt = '12/31/2009'; 
declare @dcnt int; 
;with DateList as   
 (   
    select @STARTDATE DateValue   
    union all   
    select DateValue + 1 from    DateList      
    where   DateValue + 1 < convert(VARCHAR(15),@EntDt,101)   
 )   
  select count(*) as DayCnt from (   
  select DateValue,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DateValue ) as WEEKDAY from DateList
  where DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DateValue ) not IN ( 'Saturday','Sunday' )     
  )a
option (maxrecursion 365);
```