# Inserting weekends into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, recursion

I'm trying to insert yearly weekend details such as date, dayName into a SQL Server table using the following stored procedure

```
alter procedure usp_AddOfficeHolidays
    @paramName NVARCHAR(max)
as
begin
    DECLARE @Year AS INT,
            @FirstDateOfYear DATETIME,
            @LastDateOfYear DATETIME

    -- You can change @year to any year you desire
    SELECT @year = 2016

    SELECT @FirstDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0)
    SELECT @LastDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900 + 1, 0)

    -- Creating Query to Prepare Year Data
    --declare dayN varchar(max)
    if (select COUNT(*) from tblWeekSettings) < 1
    begin
        ;WITH cte AS 
        (
            SELECT 
                1 AS DayID,
                @FirstDateOfYear AS FromDate,
                DATENAME(dw, @FirstDateOfYear) AS Dayname
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
                DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
                DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
            FROM cte
            WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, cte.FromDate) < @LastDateOfYear
        )
        SELECT FromDate AS Date, Dayname
        FROM CTE
        WHERE DayName IN (SELECT Param FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@paramName,','))
        OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)
    end
    else
    begin
        Select 'Exists'
    end
end
```

and executing it using

```
exec usp_AddOfficeHolidays 'Saturday,Sunday'
```

which returns the following result

[image]

This works perfectly fine, **BUT** I have been unable to add/insert these details into the following table

[image]

I face the following error when I try to access the WEEKEND details by its alias **CTE**

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted
>   before statement completion

Although I've added the clause

```
 OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)
```

suggested by these links which I found on stack overflow

- [The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650045/the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-statement-completion)
- [The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008129/the-statement-terminated-the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-st)

> EDIT

Basically i face the specified error when i try something like this

```
alter procedure usp_AddOfficeHolidays
@paramName NVARCHAR(max)
as
begin
----------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @Year AS INT,
@FirstDateOfYear DATETIME,
@LastDateOfYear DATETIME
-- You can change @year to any year you desire
SELECT @year = 2016
SELECT @FirstDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0)
SELECT @LastDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900 + 1, 0)
-- Creating Query to Prepare Year Data
--declare dayN varchar(max)
if (select COUNT(*) from tblWeekSettings) < 1

    begin
        ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 1 AS DayID,
        @FirstDateOfYear AS FromDate,
        DATENAME(dw, @FirstDateOfYear) AS Dayname
        UNION ALL
        SELECT cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
        DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
        DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
        FROM cte
        WHERE DATEADD(d,1,cte.FromDate) < @LastDateOfYear
        )



        SELECT FromDate AS Date, Dayname
        FROM CTE
        WHERE DayName IN(SELECT Param FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@paramName,','))

        insert into tblWeekSettings(DayNo,WeekDayName,Dates)
        values('',Dayname,Date)

        OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)
    end

else
    begin
        Select 'Exists'
    end


--select cte
-----------------------------------------------------------
end
```

Any sort of help here would really be appreciated! I just need to insert the data in my the specified table!

Thank you!

Comment: `if (select COUNT(*) from tblWeekSettings) < 1` -> `if not exists(select 1 from tbl...)`

Comment: Show full error message with sp name, line number and so on.

Comment: @ivanStarostin This stored Procedure WORKS fine i just need to insert the data into my table which i've mentioned in my question!

Comment: Is this an exercise? If not, why are you using recursion and are not exploiting the fact that a week has 7 days? You could just loop 52-53 times starting from the first weekend of the year and adding 7 days every loop.

Comment: @AimalKhan _"I face the following error when I try to access the WEEKEND details by its alias CTE"_ - show full error message with sp name, line number and so on. You are getting an exception, don't you? Show that exception without any editing.

Comment: @FDavidov not an exercise, more like a task! i mean i found this code on the internet i'm just doing my job :D If you recommend a better solution i.e. getting weekend details with dayname, date on yearly basis and inserting it in the specified table as well, i'll be happy to follow your way!

Comment: Actually that happens when i put an INSERT statement in between the code! something like this..
  .
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
  DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
  DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
  FROM cte
  WHERE DATEADD(d,1,cte.FromDate) < @LastDateOfYear
  )
  
  
  
  SELECT FromDate AS Date, Dayname
  FROM CTE
  WHERE DayName IN(SELECT Param FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@paramName,','))
  
  insert into tblWeekSettings(DayNo,WeekDayName,Dates)
  values('','','')
  
  OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)

Comment: @AimalKhan, I'll provide an answer with a logical paradigm and leave for you the details (syntax, etc.).

Comment: how about selecting into a #temp table, then inserting into your table via a select of your #temp table?  I can't understand exactly why this isn't working though, I'm wondering if your INSERT version has the maxrecursion flag on it

Comment: @Fdavidov i look forward to it. Thank you!

Comment: @andrewDeighton i can't figure that out either.

Comment: @ivanStarostin did you read my comment? i couldn't tag you into that comment cause stackoverflow didn't let me.

Comment: @AimalKhan are you getting exception _"The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion"_ or not?

Comment: @ivanStarOstin yes! Exactly.

Comment: Can you post full error message? with every technical information it contains. Not only user-readable part.

Comment: @IvanStarOstin There you go.

Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_AddOfficeHolidays, Line 18
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

BUT This only happens when i try to put an INSERT STATEMENT before this line OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)

Comment: Can you edit code in your question and add `insert` command as you add it to the version of sp which fails?

Comment: @ivanStarOstin i've edited my question!

Comment: the sql you showed us at the bottom to do the INSERT no longer seems to have maxrecursion, although it is recursive ...try....FROM CTE
        WHERE DayName IN(SELECT Param FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@paramName,','))

        insert into tblWeekSettings(DayNo,WeekDayName,Dates) OPTION (MaxRecursion 30000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the error:

```
    SELECT FromDate AS Date, Dayname
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DayName IN(SELECT Param FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@paramName,','))
```

I split this code to make you understand what code actually is working in this case:

```
    insert into tblWeekSettings(DayNo,WeekDayName,Dates)
    values('',Dayname,Date)
    OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)
```

`OPTION (MAX RECURSION)` now belongs to single insert statement. Which is standalone, totally not related to CTE.

You actually need this, I suppose:

```
    ;with CTE (...)
    insert into tblWeekSettings(DayNo,WeekDayName,Dates)
    SELECT FromDate AS Date, Dayname
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DayName IN(SELECT Param FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@paramName,','))
    OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)
```

but there are three columns in target table whilst your select has only two columns. So you'll have to update your select.

Some tips about `INSERT-SELECT`:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

this code:

```
    insert into tblWeekSettings(DayNo,WeekDayName,Dates)
    values('',Dayname,Date)
```

does not have any source for inserting. This is not valid code - you don't have here any `Dayname,Date` variables - they are not even referenced with `@` as variables. It's totally not valid code.

Comment: how do you expect to get VALUES into tblWeekSettings? Just curious!

Comment: That's what `INSERT...SELECT` statement do.

Comment: @AimalKhan you should accept this answer if it's correct.

Comment: THANK YOU @ivanStarostin.
YOUR SUGGESTION WORKED :D

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who face the following issues

- Getting Weeked details i.e. DayName, Date
- Inserting into a Table

This stored procedure would do the trick.

```
alter procedure usp_AddOfficeHolidays
@paramName NVARCHAR(max)
as
begin
----------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @Year AS INT,
@FirstDateOfYear DATETIME,
@LastDateOfYear DATETIME
-- You can change @year to any year you desire
SELECT @year = 2016
SELECT @FirstDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0)
SELECT @LastDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900 + 1, 0)
-- Creating Query to Prepare Year Data
--declare dayN varchar(max)
if (select COUNT(*) from tblWeekSettings) < 1

    begin
        ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 1 AS DayID,
        @FirstDateOfYear AS FromDate,
        DATENAME(dw, @FirstDateOfYear) AS Dayname
        UNION ALL
        SELECT cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
        DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
        DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
        FROM cte
        WHERE DATEADD(d,1,cte.FromDate) < @LastDateOfYear
        )


        insert into tblWeekSettings(DayNo,Dates,WeekDayName) 
        SELECT '',FromDate AS Date, Dayname
        FROM CTE WHERE DayName IN(SELECT Param FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@paramName,',')) 

        OPTION (MaxRecursion 30000) 




    end

else
    begin
        Select 'Exists'
    end


--select cte
-----------------------------------------------------------
end
```

Plus this article could really be helpful.

- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this is useful for you.

```
alter procedure usp_AddOfficeHolidays
@paramName NVARCHAR(max)
as
begin
----------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @Year AS INT,@DayNo as int=1,
@FirstDateOfYear DATETIME,
@LastDateOfYear DATETIME
-- You can change @year to any year you desire
SELECT @year = 2016
SELECT @FirstDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0)
SELECT @LastDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900 + 1, 0)
Select getdate() DateOfYear into #tbl where 1=0
-- Creating Query to Prepare Year Data
--declare dayN varchar(max)
if (select COUNT(*) from tblWeekSettings) < 1

    begin
            while (@FirstDateOfYear< @LastDateOfYear)
            begin
                Insert Into #tbl (DayNo,DateOfYear) values (@DayNo,@FirstDateOfYear)
                set @FirstDateOfYear+=1
                set @DayNo+=1;
            End

            Insert Into tblWeekSettings (DayNo,WeekDayName,Dates)
            SELECT DayNo,DATENAME(dw, DateOfYear) Name,DateOfYear AS Date
            FROM #tbl
            WHERE DATENAME(dw, DateOfYear) IN(SELECT Param FROM dbo.fn_MVParam(@paramName,','))

    end

else
    begin
        Select 'Exists'
    end


--select cte
-----------------------------------------------------------
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @m.jamshaidAlam But i got the answer!