# How to increase recursion value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sharepoint

When I running some reports in Sharepoint 2010, based on SQL Server 2012, they throw:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1.
>   (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
>
> Semantic query execution failed. The statement terminated. The maximum
>   recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
>   (rsSemanticQueryEngineError)

They don't contain any CTE - only derived table.

I put these reports on another server (Sharepoint 2010, SQL Server 2012) and they work. They all based on XML so I can't just write:

```
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

It's possible to set it globaly for whole database? Maybe it's another solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650045/the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-statement-completion)

Comment: @jean Please read carefully - I don't have sql query (only XML) so I need MAXRECURSION not for QUERY, but for DATABASE.

Comment: There'as no such thing as a global max recursion setting. But you can use option with any query, not only CTE `select 1 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 400)`

Comment: @jean It's any possible to use it for XML code, generated by Report Builder?

Comment: I don't know how Report Builder is quering the DB. If it's using the DB to generate de XML or if it's parsing a pre-generated XML and fetching data.  If also you don't know where (what query) is throwing that exception I suggest you to run the profile and find the offending query. That way you cna (maybe) alter it.

Comment: It's a wild guess but sometimes recursion problems in SQL are a **data integrity** problem. Like a circular reference on data. As I said that's a long shot but one you can check