# SQL Server : Longest Path

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server,  I have the (From,To) in columns From and To in a table.

```
From  To
-  -
1  5
1  7
1  8
1  17
2  11
3  5
4  7
5  12
5  13
5  17
8  13
8  17
13 17
```

How do I find the longest path between any two npoints given as input? For example, if the  input is 1,17 then the answer should be 1 - 5 - 13 - 17

Comment: define what is a path here? is this `(x,y)` coordinates in a Cartesian plane? or more like `From To`? I dont see how your example is the **longest** path. Also you mention path between two nodes `(1,17)`. What node is 1 and what node is 17? Is there an `ID` missing?

Comment: Yes, it is more like From-To. I updated the question based on your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any recursive cycles on the data?

Comment: No, the values in From and To in any given row will always be different.

Comment: You need a recursive cte  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d327/11)**

```
WITH Path ( FromID, ToID, Length, nodes ) AS (
     SELECT  t1.FromID, t1.ToID, 0 as Length, 
             CAST( t1.FromID AS VARCHAR(max) ) +'-'+ 
             CAST( t1.ToID AS VARCHAR(max) ) as nodes
     FROM Table1 t1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT P.FromID, t2.ToID, P.Length + 1, 
            P.nodes + '-' + CAST(t2.ToID AS VARCHAR(max) ) as nodes
     FROM Table1 t2
     JOIN Path  P
       ON P.ToID = t2.FromID
) 
SELECT *
FROM Path
WHERE FromID = 1
   and ToID = 17
Order by Length
```

**OUTPUT**

From 1 to 17 there is a tie with two path with length 2

```
| FromID | ToID | Length |     nodes |
|--------|------|--------|-----------|
|      1 |   17 |      0 |      1-17 |
|      1 |   17 |      1 |    1-8-17 |
|      1 |   17 |      1 |    1-5-17 |
|      1 |   17 |      2 | 1-5-13-17 |
|      1 |   17 |      2 | 1-8-13-17 |
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. With my dataset, I'm getting this error: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion. Is it possible to specify the inputs inside the CTE?

Comment: That mean either you have some cycles or too long paths. add `where length  < 100`

Comment: You can change the max recursion to allow infinite recursion if the problem are long path. But if you have cycles your query wont end. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650045/the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-statement-completion