# The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, rdbms

```sql
;WITH UserSequence AS
(
    SELECT 
        LastEnrolledOn, Users, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LastEnrolledOn) as 'Sequence'
    FROM 
        (select  sum(ct) users, LastEnrolledOn from (select  count(*) as ct,LastEnrolledOn from (select  serialnumber, LastEnrolledOn ,count(*) over (partition by [lastenrolledon]) as total 
FROM Devices) devices group by total,LastEnrolledOn )
 devciss group by LastEnrolledOn) WS1enroll
),
UserValues AS
(
  SELECT  
     u.Users AS 'UserValue', u.LastEnrolledOn, u.Sequence
  FROM UserSequence u
  WHERE Sequence = 1

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT  
     u.Users + uv.UserValue AS 'UserValue', u.LastEnrolledOn, u.Sequence
  FROM UserSequence u
  INNER JOIN UserValues uv ON u.Sequence = uv.Sequence + 1
)
SELECT
    LastEnrolledOn, Sequence, UserValue AS 'Users'
FROM 
    UserValues
ORDER BY 
    Sequence
```

I have devices table having data from almost 2013 to 2021 but not every date between. I need count total enrollment of every row with adding to next row total.  Query is working fine for few dates.

When executing whole table getting.

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: Add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the end of the statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650045/the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-statement-completion)

Comment: I suppose the real question is, do you *need* recursion? You *seem* to be describing cumulative count/sum, which doesn't require it.

Comment: Also, pet peeve, the semicolon (`;`) is a **statement terminator**; it goes at the *end* of every statement, not the start of statements that require the **previous statement** to be properly terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `option(MAXRECURSION  n)`. Here `n` is any value between 0 and 32,767. 0 means no limit but 32,767. I have added `option(maxrecursion 1000)` into your query.

```
;WITH UserSequence AS
(
    SELECT 
        LastEnrolledOn, Users, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LastEnrolledOn) as 'Sequence'
    FROM 
        (select  sum(ct) users, LastEnrolledOn from (select  count(*) as ct,LastEnrolledOn from (select  serialnumber, LastEnrolledOn ,count(*) over (partition by [lastenrolledon]) as total 
FROM Devices) devices group by total,LastEnrolledOn )
 devciss group by LastEnrolledOn) WS1enroll
),
UserValues AS
(
  SELECT  
     u.Users AS 'UserValue', u.LastEnrolledOn, u.Sequence
  FROM UserSequence u
  WHERE Sequence = 1

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT  
     u.Users + uv.UserValue AS 'UserValue', u.LastEnrolledOn, u.Sequence
  FROM UserSequence u
  INNER JOIN UserValues uv ON u.Sequence = uv.Sequence + 1
)
SELECT
    LastEnrolledOn, Sequence, UserValue AS 'Users'
FROM 
    UserValues
ORDER BY 
    Sequence
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```