# How to fix this error in ADF : "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

When I try to run a query and load the resultset into a table in Azure SQL database, I keep getting this error after the pipeline runs for some minutes.

Query:

```
  WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
    SELECT  PARENT,CHILD , 1 AS Level
    FROM P_C

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  t.PARENT, t.CHILD , c.Level + 1
    FROM   P_C t
    INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE c ON t.PARENT = c.CHILD 
)
SELECT distinct PARENT,CHILD ,Level FROM RecursiveCTE;
```

Error Details: "Azure Data Factory: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=530,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=530,State=1,Message=The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.,},],'"

How to fix this error? Please advise.

I increased the timeout minutes but no luck.

Comment: You need to debug the query. Does table `P_C` have a hierarchy more than 100 levels deep? If so you need to specify a `MAXRECURSION` value. But probably more likely you have a cycle causing infinite recursion

Comment: It has got maximum of 15 levels

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the query that you are executing because of which you are seeing this error?
Based on the error message, it seems you are using recursive CTE.
So you might need to explicitly specify max recursion:

MSFT Doc:

> An incorrectly composed recursive CTE may cause an infinite loop. For example, if the recursive member query definition returns the same values for both the parent and child columns, an infinite loop is created. To prevent an infinite loop, you can limit the number of recursion levels allowed for a particular statement by using the MAXRECURSION hint and a value between 0 and 32,767 in the OPTION clause of the INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or SELECT statement. This lets you control the execution of the statement until you resolve the code problem that is creating the loop. The server-wide default is 100. When 0 is specified, no limit is applied. Only one MAXRECURSION value can be specified per statement.

Similar thread :
[The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650045/the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-statement-completion)

Comment: Updated the question with the query