# SQL Server recursive query in a CTE issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a table called `Nodes` consisting of base doc, current doc, and target doc:

```
BaseDocType . BaseDocID
DocType . DocID
TargetDocType . TargetDocID ..
```

I want to fetch all the related nodes for any specific node. This is what I have so far:

```
WITH CTE1 (ID, BaseDocType, BaseDocID, DocType, DocID, TargetDocType, TargetDocID) AS
(
    SELECT
        ID, BaseDocType, BaseDocID, DocType, DocID, TargetDocType, TargetDocID
    FROM
        Doc.Nodes 
    WHERE
        DocType = 8 AND DocID = 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        a.ID, a.BaseDocType, a.BaseDocID, a.DocType, a.DocID, a.TargetDocType, a.TargetDocID
    FROM
        Doc.Nodes a
    INNER JOIN
        CTE1 b ON (a.BaseDocType = a.BaseDocType 
                   AND a.BaseDocID = b.BaseDocID 
                   AND a.DocType != b.DocType 
                   AND a.DocID != b.DocID)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE1
```

But the query is not working. I get this error:

> Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

![Example][1]

How can I fix this?

[here is an example that am trying to achieve][2]

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650045/the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-statement-completion

Comment: I hope you're sitting down for this, but people here aren't familiar with your database and cannot infer on how the relations between the various DocID-columns you mention work, so you might wanna explain it.

Comment: Check what the error says. Do you really expect more than 100 levels in your hierarchy? If not, either the query is bad or the data is bad, and the rows end up in circles. The 100 level limit is there to catch such errors. If you do expect more than 100 levels, seriously consider using a [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16) column instead

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? The query definitely produces cycles. In the image you posted both rows satisfy the recursive condition in relation to each other, so just those two rows are enough to produce an infinite recursion. There's no clear `ID-ParentID` relation. This looks like a *two way graph*, something that can't be represented as a hierarchy or using a recursive CTE (at least not without a very complex query). That's what [graph tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture?view=sql-server-ver16) are for.

Comment: Consider at the first level a specific pair of BaseDocType and BaseDocID.  Say (1,1). You link to a row with different DocType and DocID in the second level. But then in the third level, you can link back to the row in the first level, because its DocType and DocID would differ from the second level. You get loops that way. In summary, your query doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks for ur times guys. I uploaded another picture that illustrates am exactly am trying to do .. am trying something similar to the entity relationship document .. so I thought to build a track table that stores the current doc with the parent and child .. in another word .. next document ... previous document in otder to draw the relation on the form

Comment: Please do not use images, use table markdown

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos.. that's exactly what am trying to do. I have Sales orders connected with other marketing documents. and other documents that has been connected to that purchase orders might connect to other objects . I wanna list the hierarchy family for any specific document ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the anchor row (ID = 2) finds the related row with ID = 1, but the relationship also works in the other direction. So row 1 then finds row 2, and on and on ad infinitum. You need a termination condition of some sort on the recursion.

I'm not sure why the model given has base / document / target relationships and no target data.

Some set up with table-valued variables:

```
DECLARE @Nodes TABLE (ID INT, BaseDocType INT, BaseDocID INT, DocType INT, DocID INT, TargetDocType INT NULL, TargetDocID INT NULL);

INSERT INTO @Nodes 
VALUES 
    (1, 10, 6, 100, 2034, NULL, NULL),
    (2, 10, 6, 8, 2, NULL, NULL);
```

Rather than specifying the start document details in the anchor, you can pass those through:

```
With CTE1 (ID, StartDocType, StartDocID, BaseDocType, BaseDocID, DocType, DocID, TargetDocType, TargetDocID)
As
(
    Select ID, DocType, DocID, BaseDocType, BaseDocID, DocType, DocID, TargetDocType, TargetDocID
    From @Nodes 

    Union All

    Select a.ID, b.StartDocType, b.StartDocID, a.BaseDocType, a.BaseDocID, a.DocType, a.DocID, a.TargetDocType, a.TargetDocID
    From @Nodes a
        INNER JOIN CTE1 b 
            ON (
                a.BaseDocType = b.BaseDocType 
                AND a.BaseDocID = b.BaseDocID 
                AND a.DocType != b.DocType 
                AND a.DocID != b.DocID
                AND NOT (a.DocType = b.StartDocType AND a.DocID = b.StartDocID)
                )
)
Select *
From CTE1
Where StartDocType=8 and StartDocID = 2
```

This helps, as the recursive part can avoid reprocessing the start row and looping back from the start. However, with more data you may well hit the same issue again.

The bluntest way to terminate the recursion is to limit the recursion depth yourself by tracking the depth and limiting it in the recursive part:

```
With CTE1 (rlevel, ID, StartDocType, StartDocID, BaseDocType, BaseDocID, DocType, DocID, TargetDocType, TargetDocID)
As
(
    Select 1, ID, DocType, DocID, BaseDocType, BaseDocID, DocType, DocID, TargetDocType, TargetDocID
    From @Nodes

    Union All

    Select b.rlevel + 1, a.ID, b.StartDocType, b.StartDocID, a.BaseDocType, a.BaseDocID, a.DocType, a.DocID, a.TargetDocType, a.TargetDocID
    From @Nodes a
        INNER JOIN CTE1 b 
            ON (
                a.BaseDocType = b.BaseDocType 
                AND a.BaseDocID = b.BaseDocID 
                AND a.DocType != b.DocType 
                AND a.DocID != b.DocID
                )
    WHERE b.rlevel < 10
)
Select DISTINCT ID, BaseDocType, BaseDocID, DocType, DocID, TargetDocType, TargetDocID
From CTE1
Where StartDocType=8 and StartDocID = 2
```

There may be better ways to restrict the recursion, but that will need more knowledge of the underlying data.

Comment: million thanks to you Stephen .. I will try to test ur idea.. just I uploaded another image that describes what am trying to do .. it's just like an entity relationship map to the document in the system .. plz have a look and gimme ur opinion if u have time ..

Comment: and I guess the only terminator I am thinking of .. the start point and the endpoint .. which is the base document id is null .. and the second termination if the target document id is null . am not sure but if I can control the terminator in both directions I will bring the chain from the beginning document to the last document .. cause most or all of them may have references to each other ..